# how to point cmake to detect newer package version instead of refering the version number from apt-cache?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-installation

- I was trying to install swig in ubuntu 16.04.
- `apt-cache show swig`  showing the following

> `Package: swig
>   Priority: optional
>   Section: universe/interpreters
>   Installed-Size: 307
>   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
>   Original-Maintainer: Torsten Landschoff <torsten@debian.org>
>   Architecture: i386
>   Version: 3.0.8-0ubuntu3
>   Replaces: swig2.0
>   Depends: swig3.0 (>= 3.0.8-0ubuntu3)
>   Suggests: swig-doc, swig-examples
>   Conflicts: swig2.0
>   Filename: pool/universe/s/swig/swig_3.0.8-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
>   Origin: Ubuntu`

- I need to install `version 3.0.12`
- Downloaded the package from [official website](http://www.swig.org/download.html) as `swig-3.0.12.tar.gz` and unzipped
- Followed these [instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/swig.html)
- Installation was successful.
- Again checked the version, `sudo apt-cache show swig`

#### The version not updated to `3.0.12`.

Any help  would be appreciated !

#### EDIT 1 : I am trying to build one library using `cmake` and it requires `swig 3.0.12`. But since cmake always detects from `apt-cache` it is showing no valid version warning even if I had installed `3.0.11`. This is the case for `llvm` also.

So what I am trying to ask is , how to point cmake to detect newer package version ?

Comment: Are you sure "cmake always detects from apt-cache"? AFAIK it uses its own `FindSWIG.cmake` procedure. What does `swig -version` say?

Comment: Yeah might be , By logic I assume that, I am not sure. But as you told if it is using FindSWIG.cmake procedure , then how do I fix this ?

Comment: >`swig -version`
>```SWIG Version 3.0.8
Compiled with g++ [i686-pc-linux-gnu]
Configured options: +pcre
Please see http://www.swig.org for reporting bugs and further information
```

Comment: Well I barely understand anything about cmake, however as far as I can tell `swig` is a bit of a special case in that it's looking for an executable tool rather than traditional build dependencies (header files and libraries). In this case, the fact that `swig -version` says `3.0.8` suggests to me that your build/install of swig-3.0.12 was *not* successful (in fact it looks rather hard to do on 16.04 since it seems to require a version of libpcre3-dev that isn't even available in the 16.10 repo).

Answer (score 2):

`apt-cache show` shows the versions available / installed from the repositories or as deb-packages. It don't know anything about software you download and install by other means, like here by a tar.gz file you unpack and compile manually.

Comment: I understood your point, edited my question.